# Solve for q in the equation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How would I solve for $q$ in the equation: $ {{1}\over{p}}-{{1}\over{q}} = 3$ ?

Please show all the steps involved so I fully understand how to do it.

Comment: All you can get is 'q' in terms of 'p'......there are infinite solutions to this eqn.

Comment: That's fine, I'm told the $ q = ... $ can contain $p$

Comment: q = p/(1-3p)....then its all simple math...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the equation:

$\frac1p-\frac1q=3$

On each side, add $\frac1q$:

$\frac1p=3+\frac1q$

On each side, subtract $3$:

$\frac1p-3=\frac1q$

On each side, multiply by $q$:

$q\left(\frac1p-3\right)=1$

On each side, divide by $\left(\frac1p-3\right)$:

$q=\frac{1}{\frac1p-3}$

You can multiply the right side by $\frac{p}{p}$ if you think it looks better:

$q=\frac{p}{1-3p}$

Answer (score 1):

Notice your equation is equivalent to

$$ \frac{ 1 }{p} - 3 =  \frac{1}{q} \iff  \frac{1 - 3 p }{p} = \frac{1}{q} \iff \boxed{q = \frac{ p }{1- 3p}} $$